# How to specify which child view does not inherit shadows when setting shadows for the parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I want `bView` to be free of shadows. How can I achieve this?
I want to shadow all subviews of the superView, so I cannot remove the shadow settings of the superView.

```
let superView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
superView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
superView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
superView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
superView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
self.view.addSubview(superView)
        
let aView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
aView.backgroundColor = .white
superView.addSubview(aView)
        
let bView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 230, width: 100, height: 100))
bView.backgroundColor = .white
superView.addSubview(bView)
```

I have tried `bView.clipsToBounds = true` but it's not working.
[image]

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve. Please restate the problem and the solution you want. It would be helpful to also upload an image showing the problem and/or desired solution.

Comment: @RunLoop the solution is how to remove the shadow from bView, I have upload an image, thanks. You can run the code to try this.

Answer (score 2):

If you give `superView` a non-clear background color then none of its subviews will get a shadow. You can then apply a shadow to the subviews that you want to have a shadow.

```
let superView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 350))
superView.backgroundColor = .white // <-- Add this line
superView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
superView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
superView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
superView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
view.addSubview(superView)

let aView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
aView.backgroundColor = .white
// Add shadow to aView
aView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
aView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
aView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
aView.layer.shadowRadius = 5
superView.addSubview(aView)

let bView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 230, width: 100, height: 100))
bView.backgroundColor = .white
superView.addSubview(bView)
```

If you have several views that need a shadow then I would define a method to make it easier:

```
extension UIView {
    func addShadow() {
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
        layer.shadowRadius = 5
    }
}
```

Then your code becomes something like this:

```
let superView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 350))
superView.backgroundColor = .white
superView.addShadow()
view.addSubview(superView)

let aView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))
aView.backgroundColor = .white
aView.addShadow()
superView.addSubview(aView)

let bView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 230, width: 100, height: 100))
bView.backgroundColor = .white
superView.addSubview(bView)
```